# Does node equals node on a struct initializes the rest of the struct attributes?

Tags: c, struct, nodes

I have a struct

```
typedef struct a_struct{ 
int id;
rlnode anode;  
}AS; 

AS new;
AS old;
```

if I do this:  `new.anode = old.anode` is `new.id` is going to have the same value with `old.id`?

`rlnode` is a type of `node` nothing more.

thanks

Comment: there is no predefined type `node`, AFAIK.

Comment: No, you are assigning a single field `anode`. To assign all the fields you would use `new = old;`

Comment: If I do `j = i;`, does `n` have the same value as `m`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this statement

```
new.anode = old.anode;
```

data member `anode` of object `new` gets the value of data member `anode` of object `old`.

If you want to assign `old` to `new` then you should write

```
new = old;
```

In this case all data members of `old` will be assigned to corresponding data members of `new`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to type `new=old`. or else, only `old.anode` will be assigned to `new.anode`